# JavaScript/Ajax - How to run one PHP script before posting form to another one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am almost at my wit's end trying to figure out why my code is not working.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1) Accept several variables in a form (`myform`).

2) Using an `onsubmit`, I want to use pass one or more of those variables to a script (`process_info`).

3) After `process_info` has executed, the form should be posted to the form's action URL ('save_info.php').

As you can see in the code below, I have tried several things:

Test 1: This simple `alert` is shown and the form is submitted to `save_info.php`.

Test 2: I copied and modified this jQuery script from another page on this site.  No matter what I do, the script does not run.  I know this because no alert message is shown.

Test 3: After removing the `jQuery(document).ready` statement from Test 2, the `senddata` function runs.  Although it runs the `process_info` script, the form does not get posted to `save_info`.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Test</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
/* Test 1: this works - form is submitted to the action URL
function senddata() { alert('here'); }
*/

/* Test 2: this does not run (no alert shown) - form is submitted to the action URL */
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      function senddata() {
        var formdata = jQuery("#myform").serialize();
        var decoded = decodeURIComponent(formdata);
        strip = decoded.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "_");
//      alert(strip);
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'process_info.php',
          data: strip,
          success: function(){ alert('success'); },
          error: function(){ alert('failure'); },
          complete: function(){
              jQuery("#myform").submit(); //submit the form after ajax completes
          }
        });
        return false; //stop the form from initially submitting
      }
    });


/* Test 3: this runs and the AJAX URL is executed, "success" is displayed - form is NOT submitted to the action URL 
      function senddata() {
        var formdata = jQuery("#myform").serialize();
        var decoded = decodeURIComponent(formdata);
        strip = decoded.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "_");
//      alert(strip);
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'process_info.php',
          data: strip,
          success: function(){ alert('success'); },
          error: function(){ alert('failure'); },
          complete: function(){
              jQuery("#myform").submit(); //submit the form after ajax completes
          }
        });
        return false; //stop the form from initially submitting
      }
*/

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" id="myform" onsubmit="return senddata()" action="save_info.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="id" />
  <input type="text" name="last" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I assume that what I am trying to do is actually possible.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to change your javascript like this `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myform").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();` and then the rest of your function, also remove `onsubmit="return senddata()"` from your `<form>` tag. but i have a more fundamental fundamental question, why are you calling two different `php` files upon submit? why not combine both of them on one single file?

Comment: I am using two different php files because one of them runs on my site (`process_info.php`) and the other one (`save_info.php`) runs on another site.  I should have mentioned that in the original post.

Comment: I removed the `onsubmit` and changed the javascript as follows:  

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#myform").submit(function(event) {  
       event.preventDefault();  
       var formdata = jQuery("#myform").serialize();  
       var decoded = decodeURIComponent(formdata);  
       ...  

Is that what you meant?

This version does not execute `process_info` but does execute `save_info'.

Comment: My apologies ... I was not able to get the previous comment to format properly.  I replaced the `jQuery(document).ready(function() { function senddata() {` with `jQuery(document).ready(function() { $("#myform").submit(function(event){ event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have edited your code in a way that it works and I'll explain a few changes after the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Test</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">


/* Test 2: this does not run (no alert shown) - form is submitted to the action URL */
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myform").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
        var formdata = jQuery("#myform").serialize();
        var decoded = decodeURIComponent(formdata);
        strip = decoded.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "_");
//      alert(strip);
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'process_info.php',
          data: strip,
          success: function(){ alert('success'); },
          error: function(){ alert('failure'); },
          complete: function(){
              jQuery("#myform")[0].submit(); //submit the form after ajax completes
          }
        });
        return false; //stop the form from initially submitting
      });
    });


</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" id="myform" action="save_info.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="id" />
  <input type="text" name="last" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

So, first I have removed `onsubmit` from the `<form>` element in the `html`

Then changed the function the same as you did in your comment.

The last trick is that if I wanted to use `jQuery("#myform").submit();` in the `complete` section of the `ajax` it would add another listener for the form submit event and would call the function again and again and again.

So I had to access the HTML form element directly and call the submit for it, that's the trick as you can see `jQuery("#myform")[0].submit();`

Comment: Thank you very much!  That little "trick" made the difference.

I have been programming for a living for more than 30 years but Javascript is not my strongest language.  It never would have occurred to me to do what you did because I thought that `jQuery("#myform").submit();` was correct.

One thing that I discovered ... the "submit" button for the form must not have a name or id called "submit".  That does not work.

Once again, I appreciate your help!